# Android Studio search highlight colour very dim

Tags: android-studio, search, color-scheme

When I look at the colours set in the preferences (Preferences > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General > Search Results) the example looks fine:
[image]

However in the real world the colours are virtually impossible to distinguish:
[image]
(note the very minor difference between the "mModel"s with and without write access)

Is there some alpha transparency going on or something I can't find?
It's most annoying to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah-har, finally found it!

It's called "Identifier under caret" and "Identifier under caret (write)" and can be found in preferences under:
Editor > Color Scheme > General > Code > Identifier under caret